# Handling Recurring VBA Errors Within Subroutine

Tags: vba, error-handling

I am stuck on something that I have a workaround for, but it bugs me I don't have a direct answer for how to address the issue of using `On Error Goto` for recurring errors. My question is essentially the same [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393686/vba-error-handling-multiple-times), however the answers provided are alternatives to the OP's overall approach rather than how to handle the specific issue.

I've simplified an example below. I am ***WELL AWARE*** that there are probably a dozen ways this code could be rewritten to avoid any error -- I am just using this to illustrate the issue of trying to figure out *why/how does this code work properly when i = 0, but not when i = 3,6,9?*

```
Sub vbaErrorConfusion()
Dim theArray(9) As Long, i As Long

    For i = 0 To 9
        On Error GoTo fixingErrors
        'next line will intentionally create an error when
        'when i = {0} this works as expected, but at i=3 next line throws an error.
        theArray(i) = i + 1 / (i Mod 3)
        On Error GoTo 0
    
next_i:
    Next i

Exit Sub
'----Error Handling----
'this works as expected when i=0 but not when i = 3,6,9
fixingErrors:
    
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    'at this point I would expect my error state to be the same as the start of procedure?
    theArray(i) = -1
    GoTo next_i
End Sub
```

What my `Err` variable shows after first instance of 0.

[image]

After I run `Err.Clear` I would expect the behavior for `i=3` to be the same as when `i=0`, however my procedure stops with the below VBA error one would expect WITHOUT any error catching.

[image]

I presume there's some way to reset the `Error` variable or handle this type of situation without a workaround? Any quality responses will get upvoted. Thanks.

Comment: The answer from FreeFlow below is correct. Using Err.Clear only clears the text and numbers from the Err object it doesn't clear the error. See  [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#Using_ErrClear). It is a bit counter intuitive.

Comment: Thanks @PaulKelly (aka *King of Error Trapping* as explained in his resourceful page here: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell VBA that an you have dealt with the error you need a `Resume` statement. Therefore, replacing the line `GoTo next_i` with `Resume next_i` you give you the outcome you expect.

You do not need `Err.Clear`. Also, `On Error GoTo 0` will disable the error handler. However, neither of these lines will tell VBA that you have dealt with an error.

In your code at `i=0` the error handler is activated but VBA is not told that the error has been dealt with (i.e. no `Resume` statement). At `i=3` another error occurs while a previous error hadn't been dealt with. In this case the current procedure/function/property cannot deal with the second error, which is therefore, fatal.

You should also take the `On Error GoTo fixingErrors` line outside the loop.

```
Sub vbaErrorConfusion()
On Error GoTo fixingErrors
Dim theArray(9) As Long, i As Long

    For i = 0 To 9
        '*On Error GoTo fixingErrors
        'next line will intentionally create an error when
        'when i = {0} this works as expected, but at i=3 next line throws an error.
        theArray(i) = i + 1 / (i Mod 3)
        '*On Error GoTo 0
    
next_i:
    Next i

Exit Sub
'----Error Handling----
'this works as expected when i=0 but not when i = 3,6,9
fixingErrors:
    
    '*Err.Clear
    '*On Error GoTo 0
    'at this point I would expect my error state to be the same as the start of procedure?
    theArray(i) = -1
    Resume next_i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take some time to read up on how Error handling in VBA works.

```
Sub vbaErrorConfusion()
    Dim theArray(9) As Long, i As Long

    For i = 0 To 9
        On Error GoTo fixingErrors
        'next line will intentionally create an error when
        'when i = {0} this works as expected, but at i=3 next line throws an error.
        theArray(i) = i + 1 / (i Mod 3)
        'On Error GoTo 0
    
'next_i:
    Next i

    Exit Sub
    '----Error Handling----
    'this works as expected when i=0 but not when i = 3,6,9
fixingErrors:
    
    Err.Clear
    Debug.Print "An error was generated for i= ", i
    'On Error GoTo 0
    'at this point I would expect my error state to be the same as the start of procedure?
    theArray(i) = -1
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, your code does work but I liked the explanation provided from the other answer. I upvoted your answer here and I checked out a couple others of yours and gave this post a click as I thought it was useful (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62994772/remove-duplicates-in-vba-combobox/62996373#62996373). Thanks